# How to chcek is point in my complicated frame or not?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, region

In my MFC-application I have MianFrame and many Floating/Docking bars, Dialogs which have little in common. I need to chcek is point in my complicated frame or not. I have tried to use this code:

```
MainFrame::___
{
...
HRGN hrgn = CreateRectRgn(0,0,0,0);
int regionType = GetWindowRgn(hrgn);
if (regionType != ERROR) 
{ 
if ( !PtInRegion(hrgn, p.x, p.y) )  
    return false;
}
DeleteObject(hrgn); 
...
}
```

but regionType is always == ERROR. Can you understand why? Or, may be you know another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling GetLastError() to get a better error code.

Or you could try using GetClientRect() and PtInRect() and see if that gives better results.

Comment: GetClientRect() does not suit here. Where shoul I call GetLastError()?

Comment: Call it right after GetWindowRgn(). It may or may not give better info but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetWindowRect() to get a 'rect', then HRGN hrgn = CreateRectRgn(0,0,0,0), then SetRectRgn using the hrgn and 'rect'. As long as SetRectRgn returns normally, your code is fine.

I am also new to this. Does hrgn need to be inited?